# Compatibility between New-WebServiceProxy and a proxy server

Tags: powershell

Am I missing something here?

Does new-webserviceproxy not support proxy credentials?

Corporate environments invariably use proxy servers to talk to the rest of the web and I can't seem to get new-webserviceproxy to talk through ours. I get a 407 proxy authentication required error in return - the credentials argument is for credentials to the webservice not for the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this cmdlet has no support for proxy credentials. You may want to try using the code posted here by Lee.
http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/02/28/calling-a-webservice-from-powershell/

He uses NET.WebClient namespace and hence it is possible to add proxy credentials to the connect-WebService code.